# definite integrals sequence - uniformly convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, definite-integrals

Let $f_0$ be Riemann integrable on the domain $[0,2]$

define sequence of functions for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in [0,2]$

$f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f_{n-1}(t)\:dt$

does this sequence uniformly converge on the domain [0,2]?

I feel like this statement isn't correct but can't come up with proper counter example. also, I proved with induction that each function in the sequence is continues and tried to use the fundamental theorem but it's pretty much coming to a dead-end because I don't have more information about the functions and not a limit function in this case.

Comment: Don't you think the way you are constructing $\{f_n\}$, all $f_n$ are constants for all $n\geq 1$? See that $f_1 = \int\limits_{0}^{2}f_0(t)dt$ is independent of $x$.

Comment: You're right I mistyped it, edited tnx!

Comment: $f_0$ is bounded. Let $\sup\limits_{x\in[0,2]} |f_0(x)|= M$. Then, it is easy to see by induction that 
$$|f_n(x)| \leq \frac{Mx^n}{n!}\leq \frac{M2^n}{n!},$$
for every $x$ in $[0,2]$. Clearly, 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{M2^n}{n!}=0,$$
which confirms that the given sequence of functions converges uniformly to 0.